# Is this design too convoluted?

Tags: design, solid

I'm trying to experiment with SOLID in order to get a better grasp of its' concepts.  With that in mind, I'm making a card game project.

There's a GameUtils project that contains the following classes: IPlayer, ICard, and IDeck.

Then there are projects for each game, such as Hearts, GoFish, and War.  Inside those projects there's a super Player(i.e. HeartsPlayer,WarPlayer) that implements the IPlayer interface, but have game specific methods.  Below that there's two subclasses, HumanPlayer, and CompPlayer that implement the AI player and human interactions.

My question is, is this a little too much? Should I drop IPlayer and just have the player specific classes inside their respective game projects?

Example attempt at UML:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> There's a GameUtils project that contains the following classes: IPlayer, ICard, and IDeck.

'Utils' are helpers (i.e. utilities), which are ancillary services. Players, cards and decks are **cornerstones** of a card game. The name for the collection does not accurately describe what's in the collection.

Furthermore, interfaces are definitely not helpers, since helper focus on *logical implementation*, not contract design.

> My question is, is this a little too much? Should I drop IPlayer and just have the player specific classes inside their respective game projects?

My main feedback on this shared project is **what does this shared ancestry provide for you?**

Generally speaking, the existence of a shared ancestor implies that there is *some* kind of reused logic that can handle every kind of subtype (whether interface implementor or class inheritor). However, you have not shown any use case for this, so I can't vet that this shared logic has a valuable purpose.

What I *worry* about here is that you've built this purely in pursuit of a problem that you can then use SOLID on, rather than because the actual codebase requires it, and **that is an exercise in dogmatic design** which should be avoided at all times. Dogma (as opposed to pragmatism) is an act of doing more than you need to do, which is inherently negative as it ups the complexity which in turn creates many negative effects on the developer experience (bug likelihood, debugging effort, regressions, maintainability, onboarding, ...).

To put it differently, "if you build it, they will come" is a really bad software development methodology. It least to massive amounts of overdesign and wasted effort. A much more efficient process would be "they want to come, so I will build it for them", i.e. understand what you need before you decide to build it.

It's okay to dream up a codebase to practice your development process, but the design of that codebase shouldn't make itself more complex than it actually needs to be. If you need more complexity, you should define more complicated requirements, rather than trying to achieve a simple goal in a more complex way.

> Then there are projects for each game, such as Hearts, GoFish, and War.

All good. It helps separate the implementation which does make sense.

> Inside those projects there's a super Player(i.e. HeartsPlayer,WarPlayer)

At the very least, there's a bit of [smurf naming convention](https://devcards.io/smurf-naming-convention) going on here.

Given that these are separate projects, there should already be a scope to each given project. You didn't specify a language so I'm not sure if there's e.g. an assembly-based or namespace-based scope, but them being in different project implies that there's *some* kind of separation going on here that would allow you to simply name this class `Player` in each project.

However, I'm more so going to question your reliance on inheritance. This isn't strictly SOLID, but [composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) is equally important and does actually align spiritually with what SOLID aims to achieve.

One example here is the distinction between human players and AI players. When you think about it, the role of a player, as described by the game rules, does not change based on who is the "brains" that drives the player's actions. You can think of the player role as a [video game controller](https://www.dimensions.com/collection/video-game-controllers-gamepads). Describing how such a controller works is completely independent of who is holding the controller, and therefore inheritance doesn't make sense here.

What is also missing here is the **composing game logic**, which is the end goal here. You're not trying to showcase a data design for card game components, you're trying to build a game. The only reason you create these components is because they aid you in implementing that game logic. You cannot judge if your design makes sense if you haven't even built that logic.

You're asking me to judge if this is a good hammer, without me seeing a board or the nails. I can't answer that. I can point at some obvious things based on what I *infer* your intentions are with this hammer (e.g. don't use a glass handle), but I can't rate it fully unless I see you using it.

---

I think you modeled a design without a true purpose, which makes it hard to (a) figure out what it is that you need and (b) subsequently confirm that you've built it correctly.

I suggest you do it the other way around. Start with the game logic. During that implementation process, whenever you uncover the need for an additional component, develop that component **so that it achieves what it needs to achieve for the game logic's purpose**.

For example, your game starts with dealing cards to players. Already, this tells you that you need to know what a card is (including a distinct identifier to tell cards apart), a deck which is just a bunch of cards in a given order, and a player component who can hold a set of cards.

Therefore, the first iteration of your design would have you reach a state that models the beginning of the game: there are X players, there is a (presumably shuffled) deck, each player has been distributed the correct amount of cards, the remaining deck is also available.

And then you revisit the implementation of the game logic. Use the components you just built, and construct your game logic until you notice that you need some more components to progress.

What that next step is highly depends on the specific game, but the abstract process is the same: **formulate what you need**, and then build the thing that gets you to that goal. I have bolded this because I think this is what you're currently lacking.

One thing I can already suggest to you is that there's little purpose to figuring out a computer player before you have a working game (with all human players, even if they're all controlled by you with perfect knowledge of everyone's hands). The computer player would need to be able to play the game, which implies that at this stage the game logic is already implemented *so that the computer player can therefore do things*.

Comment: That reference to "smurf naming" was an interesting one.  I've not heard it before!  It does seem like an interesting policy to think through before implementing.  If *all* of your tools are good at showing namespaces, it's probably wise, but I can't count the number of times I've pulled my hair out debugging python while screaming "WHICH `Callback` class is this?!?!"

Comment: I'll go back and simplify a bit. And calling it GameUtils might be the wrong thing, but it does contain shared logic that all sub projects will require. Originally I was going to start writing my own UNO, then broke down to Hearts, and now GoFish as a start.  The Deck is the same for all projects, and I didn't think I needed to repeat logic for that. ICard is just a model, and doesn't need any special logic either.

Comment: I also re-evaluated the structure for these interfaces, and honestly, ICard, and IPlayer can be nuked. If anything I could rename GameUtils to GameFramework.

Comment: @CortAmmon: I'm coming at this from a .NET / Visual Studio / JetBrains Rider perspective, but both the IDE and exceptions tell you the namespace so the same info is available compared to when you had smurf-named it. Also, .NET allows you to rename types in a file if you want, e.g. `using SmurfFoo = MyApp.Smurf.Foo;`, which is helpful e.g. when mapping from one namespace's `Foo` to another namespace's `Foo`, without needing to smurf-name it for _all_ of your codebase.

Comment: @CBredlow: _"but it does contain shared logic that all sub projects will require"_ Even if all utils are inherently shared between projects, that does not mean that everything that's shared between projects should therefore be a util.

Comment: @CBredlow _"ICard is just a model"_ Interfaces are contracts. In all my experience, "model" refers to a concrete class (often just a data structure). I'm not opposed to a reused implementation of a deck and cards, but not as interfaces, and not in a "utils" category (I'm more inclined to call that the domain)

Answer (score 3):

These "util" interfaces just specify a split of responsibilities that
will allow you to start quickly with new card games. They do not make it too convoluted: if you wouldn't have them, you'd probably have to either define them in each game, or define them implicitly with classes.

Now that you have a big picture in mind, **don't  overthink it**: it'd be the best way to get stuck in endless theoretical thoughts about the best design.

Go and **start your first game** using these interfaces. Then assess: is there some general game logic that you could reuse (e.g base classes, enrichment's of the interfaces etc...). Then **refactor** your game and move those to your game **utils**.

This approach will help you to **apply SOLID on more focused problems** where you can  understand the pros and cons of the principles much better than on a diagram which seems convoluted but doesn't cover the real challenges. Because there's not much evidence of SOLID so far.

The utils will gradually evolve into a **framework**.  Then implement your second game, assess, refactor, and so on.

Thinking too much in an early stage, will get you stuck, and will prevent you discovering what elements really will matter. Alternatively, read a book like "Game coding complete" to fast forward you in your framework. But it'll still **delay you from delivering any fun game yourself** ;-)